# Conditional XML Modify in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to use XML.modify within a case statement like this or would this have to be 2 separate update statements?

```
UPDATE s
SET     
   CASE WHEN [XMLData] IS NOT NULL THEN [XMLData].modify('delete //invoice/account/contactinformation') END,
   CASE WHEN [SummaryXMLData] IS NOT NULL THEN [SummaryXMLData].modify('delete //invoice/account/contactinformation') END 
FROM   
    ITS_CSC.[Statement].[StatementSummary] s
```

SQL Server throws this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

NB: Calling the `modify` method directly on a `NULL` value fails with the following message hence need to check for `NULL`s

> Mutator 'modify()' on 'column name' cannot be called on a null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is incorrect syntax. You could use 2 separate statements instead:

```
UPDATE ITS_CSC.[Statement].[StatementSummary]
SET  [XMLData].modify('delete //invoice/account/contactinformation') 
WHERE [XMLData] IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE ITS_CSC.[Statement].[StatementSummary]
SET [SummaryXMLData].modify('delete //invoice/account/contactinformation')
WHERE [SummaryXMLData] IS NOT NULL;
```